# Groovy: search for a data based on date range in mongodb from groovy

Tags: mongodb, date, groovy, isodate

I'm using ART(A Reporting Tool) tool wherein we're trying to display the data between a given date range using groovy.

I'm using mongodb, searching between date range is taken care by mongo queries(in ISO date format). I'm not sure how to add ISO date to the search query in groovy for mongodb.
Please suggest me how I can fix this or is there any alternative for a date range without using ISO date format

Here's my code which I tried. I'm getting empty result

```
import org.bson.Document;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCursor;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject

def dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
def dateString = "2020-08-18T18:30:00Z"
def date = Date.parse(dateFormat, dateString)

def now1 = date.format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
def isodate = 'ISODate(\"' + now1 + '\")'
searchObj = [date: ['$gte': isodate]]
MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("DBName");
MongoCollection < Document > collection = db.getCollection("DBCollection");
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject(searchObj)

MongoCursor < Document > cursor = collection.find(query).iterator();

List < Document > records = new ArrayList < > ();
try {
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        records.add(cursor.next());
    }
} finally {
    cursor.close();
}

return records;
```

I'm able to get the result using this query in mongo shell, but it's not working from groovy

```
>db.dbCollection.find({date:{$gte:ISODate("2020-08-18T18:30:00Z")}})

{
        "_id" : XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
        "date" : ISODate("2020-08-23T18:30:00Z"),
        "name" : "nathan",
        "age"  : 27
}
{
        "_id" : XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
        "date" : ISODate("2020-08-23T18:30:00Z"),
        "name" : "steve",
        "age"  : 23
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never used mongodb, but it seems to me that the mongodb java api uses static methods from the [mongodb Filters class](https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.0/?com/mongodb/client/model/Filters.html) to represent comparison operators like `%gte`. So you would do something like:

```
static import com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.*
...
def cursor = collection.find(gte('date', isodate)).iterator()
...
```